# Rollback transaction in MySQL

Tags: mysql, transactions, mysql-workbench, transactional

I need help with a rollback. I need to insert in table `CATEGORIA` **ONLY** when I insert into `CATEGORIA_IDIOMA`. So I tried a TRANSACTION, but it does not work, I have a UNIQUE CONSTRAINT IN `CATEGORIA_IDIOMA` FOR (id_idioma, nombre_categoria). The code for my STORED PROCEDURE is:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_ingresar_categoria
(
    IN AV_CATEGORIA_NOMBRE VARCHAR(255), 
    IN AI_ID_IDIOMA INT
)
BEGIN

    DECLARE EXIT handler for sqlexception
    BEGIN
        SELECT 'EXISTE UN ERROR, NO SE PUDO INGRESAR LA CATEGORIA'
        ROLLBACK;
    END;

    START TRANSACTION;

        INSERT INTO `CATEGORIA`(`activo`) 
        VALUES (1);

        SELECT MAX(`id_categoria`) INTO @LI_CATEGORIA from `CATEGORIA`;

        INSERT INTO `CATEGORIA_IDIOMA`(`id_categoria`, `id_idioma`, `categoria_nombre`)
        VALUES(@LI_CATEGORIA, AI_ID_IDIOMA, AV_CATEGORIA_NOMBRE);

        commit;
END //
```

When I try it with a new value, it works fine, but when I try it with a duplicated value, it does not insert into `CATEGORIA_IDIOMA`, but it inserts into `CATEGORIA`.

Can someone explain me how it works, or where is my error please.

Comment: "it does not insert into CATEGORIA_IDIOMA, but it inserts into CATEGORIA."...are you sure? Are you basing that on the SELECT which occurs during the transaction? Or did you test it again after the transaction should have been rolled back?

Comment: Two suggestions:  (1) read about `LAST_INSERT_ID()`. A notorious antipattern:  `SELECT MAX(id) FROM....` . (2) show us your table definitions including columns and indexes. `SHOW CREATE TABLE whatever` gets what we need.

Comment: @O.Jones I didn´t know about LAST_INSERT_ID(), I´m gonna change my code to use this function, I hope this solve the problem

Comment: @ADyson I´m sure. What I want to do is to get the id provided by AUTO_INCREMENT in order to make the second insert with it.

Comment: Use an `AUTO_INCREMENT` for the column `CATEGORIA_IDIOMA`.`id_categoria` in MySQL, so you don't need to execute `SELECT MAX(...)`.